# Can we have our comments indexed?

Tags: feature-request

Occasionally I leave a comment and forget about it, and I would like to be able to go back and find them without remembering the general context of the question (which I did not answer) and searching for that. Is this possible, or would it strain the servers too much?

Answer (score 2):

We currently have the following:

( stackoverflow | meta.stackoverflow | serverfault | superuser ).com [/api/userquestions.html](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?page=1&pagesize=10&userId=130154&sort=)
( stackoverflow | meta.stackoverflow | serverfault | superuser ).com [/api/useranswers.html](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?page=1&pagesize=30&userId=130154&sort=)
( stackoverflow | meta.stackoverflow | serverfault | superuser ).com [/api/userfavorites.html](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.html?page=1&pagesize=15&userId=130154&sort=)

Now we need:

/api/usercomments.html

Comment: wait,          what?

Comment: I'm confused....when did we get an API?

Comment: It's an internal API for ajax requests.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we need to do something to better surface comments for reference. Right now the only answer is google at the moment.

Comment: +1 for "Right now [...] at the moment."